# $.each не выводит все параметры, а только последнй

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь вывести все параметры, но $.each отрисовывает только последний, хотя в консоле все есть.

```
$.each(data, function(index, person) {
                var output = "<tr>";
                output += "<td>" + person.name + "</td>";
                output += "<td><select name='persons[]'>";
                $.each(person.variants, function(i,value){
                    output += "<option>" + value.name + "</option>";
                });
                output += "</select></td>";
                output += "</tr>";
                console.log(filter);
                $('#results').html(output);
            });
```

Почему он выводит только последнее значение, а не все которые есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что вы каждый раз перезаписываете свой же результат в строке:

```
$('#results').html(output);
```

Что бы работало, сделайте прибавление.

```
$('#results').html($('#results').html() +  output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Он выводит каждое значение, но Вы сейчас же затираете его следующим
(и не успеваете его прочитать :) ).

```
var output = "";
$.each(data, function(index, person) {
  output += "<tr>";
  ...
});
$('#results').html(output);
```

P.S.
Что такое `filter`?

Comment: Ыть) это я чет с другого кода сюда вставил случайно))Не выходит с вашим советом. С нижним ответом все вышло

Comment: @Alex_01 - Бывает. Должно выходить. Совет хороший - не сомневайтесь. Удачи.

Comment: спасибо) буду пользоваться ив вашим советом